# SQL where value OR value is between range

Tags: mysql, sql

So basically I have the following query

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.number
     , t.capacity
     , b.reservation_code
     , b.reservation_date
     , r.start_time
     , r.end_time 
  FROM tables t 
  JOIN bookings b 
  JOIN reservation_time_data r 
    ON r.id = b.reservation_time 
 WHERE b.table_no = t.number 
   AND reservation_date LIKE '%2020-07-25%' 
   AND r.start_time BETWEEN '19:00:00.0000' AND ADDTIME('19:00:00.0000', '1:45:0.000000')
```

This functions as intended, but I need to add to add an OR clause. Id like it to be where `r.start_time` OR `r.end_time` is between...

I have tried doing `WHERE r.start_time OR r.end_time BETWEEN...`

and I have tried adding `OR r.end_time BETWEEN..`

to the end of the query. Each of this doesn't work as it should return me just one extra row (the original returns 2). But when I run either of the 2 attempts it returns me like 400+ rows. There isn't even 400 rows in the targeted table haha

Comment: You also want to return results from the year 12020, say?

Comment: Does you need in the rows where `start_time` is before specified interval and `end_time` is after it (the interval is fully covered)?

Comment: Why are you using `like` with a date?  What is the ultimate logic you want to implement?

Comment: I really doubt that the accepted answer is actually what you're looking for. What if r.start_time is before 19 and r.end_time is after 20.45? Why would you want to exclude that from your result !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry The difference between the two is always 1 hour and 45 mins

Comment: Well, in that case the solution is probably fair enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that the duration is always 1:45:00...

You have to specify `BETWEEN` separately for each of the two time fields:

```
AND (
  r.start_time BETWEEN '19:00:00.0000' AND ADDTIME('19:00:00.0000', '1:45:0.000000')
  OR
  r.end_time BETWEEN '19:00:00.0000' AND ADDTIME('19:00:00.0000', '1:45:0.000000')
)
```

Comment: @TiernO Note that this might fits your needs `AND r.start_time >= '19:00:00.0000' AND  r.end_time <= ADDTIME('19:00:00.0000', '1:45:0.000000')`, it should give you the expected results if your system correctly tracks start and end session times. The advantage is that you avoid an `OR`, which is sometimes a perf killer

Comment: @ThomasG What you are suggesting is very different from what the OP is asking.  The OP is looking for records where at least one of start/end time is in the given range.  Your AND clause will return records where the entire interval is inside the range - which is VERY different.

Comment: @AleksG Dont worry I perfectly know what was in the question and what was in my comment. And it all starts like this: _"Note that this might fits your needs"_ for a reason. OP might not necessary knows that a simplest solution exists following how its data is recorded by the source application